# How to save sklearn model parameters in a json file?

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Suppose I have very simple machine learning model as follows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, StackingRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
estimators = [
    ('lr', RidgeCV()),
    ('svr', LinearSVR(random_state=42))
]
reg = StackingRegressor(
    estimators=estimators,
    final_estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,
                                          random_state=42)
)
steps = [
    ("preprocessing", StandardScaler()),
    ("regression", reg)
]
pipe = Pipeline(steps)
```

What I would like to do is to store the whole model parameter as json file. By that I mean the following information is saved in json file.

```
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessing', StandardScaler()),
            ('regression',
             StackingRegressor(estimators=[('lr',
                                            RidgeCV(alphas=array([ 0.1,  1. , 10. ]))),
                                           ('svr',
                                            LinearSVR(random_state=42))],
                               final_estimator=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,
                                                                     random_state=42)))])
```

When I use `json.dumps(pipe)` I face with error that `Object of type Pipeline is not JSON serializable`. Any idea how one can do that?

Comment: It seems that the `Pipeline` code you `import` contains methods and/or other imports that can't be put into JSON. Maybe you should only serialize the variables you set and not try to include the whole Pipeline class into the json file.

Comment: We usually use pickle for saving model artifacts, you can find more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html.

Comment: @Kokodoko: Thanks for the quick response! My goal of saving only model parameter (in kind of text format) is to store this information in SQL table, so that one can later use this information and reproduce the data. I was thinking a nice way could be storing model parameter in json format which is easily readable in the SQL table.

Comment: To be clear, you want the model's definition, not the fitted attributes (like `coef_`)?

Comment: @BenReiniger: Yes. For me the model information is important. Here, in this example, it is important to know that one preprocessing step has been done (StandardScaler) which is followed by StackingRegressor with specified hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

The output you've given is just the string representation, so `str(pipe)` will produce that.  It has a bit of formatting for spacing and newlines, so perhaps not ideal for storage.

You could use `pipe.get_params()` to retrieve a dictionary of parameters.  That will include all the default parameters unlike the string; you could use the private method `_changed_params` from `sklearn.utils._pprint` ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f71c0313142c4e5f2f35a0021c36075cf8dba611/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py#L89)), but being private you'd need to be careful about breaking changes.  There might be a more public method along the lines of pretty-printing and display of estimators that gives you what you need.